# Hidden file names in URLs in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am developing java application.I want to hide the jsp and html page.
    please any body know please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by hide? Do you mean you want to hide the extension from the user?

If that is the case, then please indicate what kind of application stack you have.

Are you using a servlet container with Apache httpd in front? This is quite common. In that case you have several options, including [mapping URLs to filesystem locations in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/urlmapping.html) (for the .html files) and configuring your web application in your web.xml with [JSP handlers](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1583).